# Program.cs and Startup.cs in a Blazor Server app

Tags: c#, configuration, config, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server application where I added a "Startup" class manually, because I needed to configure some things and I thought that is the best way. However I am an extreme beginner in anything web and am now wondering if I did the right call.

My current predicament is that I want to enable detailed errors ONLY if the environment is "Development" but with my current setup it looks hard to do.

The line of code I intend to use is this one: `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseSetting(WebHostDefaults.DetailedErrorsKey, "true")`

But getting `IWebHostEnvironment` seems quite tricky at the place where I'm creating the default builder.

This is my `Program.cs`:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InitKeyVault();
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
                {
                    var connection = KeyVaultReader.GetSecretValue("AzureAppConfigConnStr");
                    config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
                        options.Connect(connection)
                        .UseFeatureFlags(flagOptions =>
                        {
                            flagOptions.Label = "Label";
                            flagOptions.CacheExpirationInterval = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
                        })
                        .Select(KeyFilter.Any, LabelFilter.Null)
                        .Select(KeyFilter.Any, "Label")
                        .Select(KeyFilter.Any, "Another Label"));
                }).UseStartup<Startup>());

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialises <see cref="KeyVaultReader"/>, which is used to retrieve secrets from Azure Key Vault.
    /// </summary>
    public static void InitKeyVault()
    {
        SecretClientOptions options = new SecretClientOptions()
        {
            Retry =
            {
                Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
                MaxDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(16),
                MaxRetries = 5,
                Mode = RetryMode.Exponential
            }
        };

        string keyVaultAddress = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KeyVault-Address");
        KeyVaultReader.secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultAddress), new DefaultAzureCredential(), options);
    }
}
```

and this is my `Startup.cs`:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

        // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
        services.AddAuthorization(options => options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy);

        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();
        services.AddFeatureManagement();
        services.AddAzureAppConfiguration();

        services.AddSingleton<FirstService>();
        services.AddSingleton<SecondService>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days.You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAzureAppConfiguration();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        bool hubFound = HubRegistry.TryFindHubAddress(typeof(MessagesHub), out string messagesHubAddress);
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            if (hubFound)
                endpoints.MapHub<MessagesHub>(messagesHubAddress);
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
}
```

Have I done something wrong so far?

If `YES` how to fix it?

Comment: Do you build and run it? What exactly problem do you have?

Comment: @kanils_, it runs fine, I'm wondering if it isn't structured poorly, plus now I have to do code gymnastics if I want to set it so that detailed errors are only showed in dev environment, because I have to pass the `IHostEnvironement` somehow in Program.cs

Comment: @Tessarct detailed errors, like `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` ? Like that [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5cdS.png)

Comment: @kanils_, no like `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseSetting(WebHostDefaults.DetailedErrorsKey, "true")` which is very clearly and obviously written in the question.